# How to resolve this error in telepot library?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram, telepot

hope it's ok i was compiling a little code for a smart doorbell project when all of a sudden this error appears to me is there a solution?

I use python 3.7 and the latest version of telepot library in raspberry pi3B

sorry my english is because i'm using google translator

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1182, in get_from_telegram_server
    allowed_updates=allowed_upd)
  
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
 
 File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telepot/api.py", line 155, in request
    return _parse(r)
  
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telepot/api.py", line 150, in _parse
    raise exception.TelegramError(description, error_code, data)

telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running', 409, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 409, 'description': 'Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running'})
```

My code: https://pastebin.com/2byH6evT

If you need any information, contact me

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found out myself how to reslver I basically reinstalled the Telepot and it started working
Thank you very much to all who viewed and Help :)

RZG